# Calendar.set error or infinite loop

Tags: groovy, calendar

the following does not seem to work, it seems to cause an infinite loop:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

SimpleDateFormat out=new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');

def from = Calendar.instance
from.set(year: 2017, month: Calendar.JANUARY, date: 3)

def to = Calendar.instance
to.set(year: 2017, month: Calendar.FEBRUARY, date: 3)

from.upto(to) {

    cal=it;
    prev=cal;
    prev.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    println out.format(prev.getTime());
}
```

can somebody please explain why this should not work? I don't get it. My goal is to get the first day of month within the upto loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop, you are constantly setting the calendar back to the first day of the month...

It's similar to if you did:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    i = 0
    println i
}
```

(that will never finish either)

Also, you code will run for every day between the two dates...  which I don't think is what you are looking for either

It's easier if you use immutable things over Calendar, and as you're on Java 8, you can do:

```
import java.time.*
import java.time.format.*

// Add a next method, so you can do ranges of LocalDates    
LocalDate.metaClass.next = { delegate.plusDays(1) }

LocalDate from = LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 3)
LocalDate to   = LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 3)

(from..to).each { 
    println it.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE) + " : " + it.withDayOfMonth(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)
}
```

Comment: ok I got it. But actually this is yet my goal, I need to display the date of the loop and the first day of the month such as:
2017-01-03 / 2017-01-01
2017-01-04 / 2017-01-01
...
2017-02-01 / 2017-02-01

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: yes Sir. There is a possibility to skip the Calendar part, isn'it?

Comment: Yup...I'll come up with something non-calendar and cleaner...one sec

Comment: many many thanks tim. this works like a charm and now I have a basis to work with Java 8 style

Comment: Cool :-)  Enjoy!!